# Get a std::thread to detach and terminate itself

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently developing a basic thread pool. I used c++11's `std::thread`, along with `std::condition_variable`, and `std::unique_lock`. It seems to work, and I now would like to be able to kill some threads when too many of them are inactive.
For now, their jobs are given through a `std::queue` of `boost::function`s. I was thinking of adding a bunch of empty `boost::function`s so the threads know they have to exit their loop.
The thread's loop is like this:

```
void    ThreadPool::threadLoop()
{
  boost::function<void ()>      oThreadTask;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  oLock(m_oTaskMutex);

  while (1)
    {
      // m_oCV is a static std::condition_variable
      // m_oTaskQueue is a static std::queue< boost::function<void ()> >
      m_oCV.wait(oLock, [](){ return m_oTaskQueue.size(); });
      oThreadTask = m_oTaskQueue.front();
      m_oTaskQueue.pop();
      m_oTaskMutex.unlock();
      if (oThreadTask.empty())
        break ;
      oThreadTask();
    }
  // ??
}
```

The thing is, I'm not sure how to properly detach the thread once I exited the loop.
Would it be clean to look for the thread's handle (I have access to a `std::list<std::thread*>`, and can compare their ids with `std::this_thread::get_id()`), and is it safe to call `detach()` from the thread itself, or even `join()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you have all thread objects stored, you can find the one which `thread::id` is equal to `this_thread::get_id()`, and you can call `detach()` on it, and destroy the thread object after that (the C++11 standard does not prevent that, and I believe it is based on the common practice). Make sure that no other execution thread accesses the instance of `std::thread` which is destroyed.

But you cannot call `join()` from the thread itself: an attempt for a thread to join with itself would result in a deadlock, and C++11 implementations should recognize that and throw `system_error` with the error condition of `resource_deadlock_would_occur`.

Alternatively, you can leave a message (e.g. via an std::atomic variable) to the main thread that the thread associated with a particular instance of `std::thread` is about to complete its execution, and let the main thread join with this instance at a later point.

Comment: Thank you. The easiest way will probably to make threads detach themselves.